# Using the second Ethernet Port for TCP on a NI PXI with LABVIEW

Tags: tcp, ethernet, labview, pharlap

I'm using a PXI 8109 running Pharlap OS.

I'm trying to use the second ethernet interface of my PXI to send UDP and TCP packets.

Here the configuration of my two ethernet interfaces:

```
eth0 (primary):
IP : 10.0.0.3
subnet mask : 255.0.0.0


eth1 :
IP : 192.168.10.9
subnet mask : 255.255.255.0
```

For UDP, I have no problems, packets are sent to the second interface as I want. I think it work because there is a "net address" input on the "UDP Open" VI so the system can choose the right interface.

For TCP, I use the "TCP Open connection" VI but there is no this kind of input. And it is not working : I assume the system is trying to use the primary interface but it can't route packets...

For information, my two networks are physically independant.

Can you help me finding out what's going on ? Is it possible to use TCP on the second ethernet interface ?

Comment: I'm in touch with NI team and will keep you informed when I find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem. This was not related to the TCP connection ...

I was using a property node "Value (signaling)" to trigger the TCP connection and it seems that this is not supported on RT Targets.
This is why it was working on localhost.

Thanks for the help anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

TCP open is meant to open a connection to another computer, if you feed a valid (in one of the two subnets) TCP address it should open a connection on that specific interface.

I assume you need to use the TCP listener function and according to [this KB article](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/AE69890A3DB5329386256C4F006F7A5E), you can specify on which address you want to listen. So yes, you should be able to use a specific ethernet interface.

*disclaimer*: I am not sure if all this info is valid on Pharlap as well.

Comment: But, TCP listener is to create a TCP server ; it will work if a client start the connection with me. 

But in my case, my application is the TCP client, so I can't use TCP listen, I need to use TCP open. Am I wrong ?

Comment: No you are right. However on the TCP open connection you can insert an address as well (see http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvcomm/tcp_open_connection/)

Comment: yes but this is the remote address for the TCP connection :) thanks anyway

Comment: So you mean that the TCP open connection with a target address of 192.168.10.10 is not connecting over the second port? Could you add a snippet of your code?

Comment: yes sure. I didn't find how to add a file to the question so here is a link to a VI file : https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B00_dhbczrP1X1pkcUNQOFk5N28/edit?usp=sharing

This is a REALLY simplified version of my code because the real code is in a Veristand Custom Device. The code works fine if the custom device is running on localhost (my windows laptop => I only have the problem when it runs on Phar Lap ; maybe because there are two ethernet ports on the PXI)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the decision which NIC to use is up to the OS and I believe that normally it would choose based on the subnet **of the address you're trying to connect to** and those of the NICs - I don't know what the IP address is (maybe it's in the subnet of the wrong card?), but the subnets of the NICs certainly appear to be different from each other (10.0.0.0 and 192...).

On Windows, I believe you can set the routing tables to have some more control of this (although I don't know if you would be able to force something to go through the "wrong" NIC), but I have no idea how much control you would have over this on Phar Lap. I would suggest some searching. Here are a couple of relevant links:

http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/RT-How-do-I-use-two-independent-Ethernet-ports/td-p/721269

http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Communicating-through-two-ethernet-ports-on-the-same-computer/m-p/1509450#M565374

Comment: I'm trying to reach a board at IP "192.168.10.10", so basically, the OS should choose the 2nd NIC. I'll check your link, but I already saw the first one in my previous search. thanks!